# Label timestamps in between time intervals of another df in Python

Tags: python, pandas, timestamp

I would like to label timestamps in df_A based on start and end time intervals in df_B:

```
df_A:  
timestamp               values 
2017-05-16 12:00:02     x  
2017-05-16 12:00:04     x  
2017-08-12 22:01:06     Y


df_B:

start                   end                     label
2017-05-08 11:00:02     2017-05-18 11:00:02     Cat1
2017-05-15 12:10:09     2017-05-20 11:00:02     Cat1
2017-10-03 19:00:12     2017-10-04 11:00:02     Cat5
```

The rule is that if the timestamp in df_A is in **any** time intervals in df_B, then copy the label value in df_B. Expected result looks like:

```
df_A:  
timestamp               values     label
2017-05-16 12:00:02     x          Cat1
2017-05-16 12:00:04     x          Cat1
2017-08-12 22:01:06     Y          NaN
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try *cross* `merge` then only keep the rows where `timestamp` in `df_A` is in time intervals in `df_B`,

```py
label = (pd.merge(df_A, df_B, how='cross')
         .query('(start < timestamp < end)')
         .groupby('timestamp')['label'].agg(set)  # Depending on which label you want to keep, you can use different methods here
         # .groupby('timestamp')['label'].agg(pd.Series.mode) # such as keep the most common value
         )

df_A['label'] = df_A['timestamp'].map(label)
```

```
print(label)

timestamp
2017-05-16 12:00:02    {Cat1}
2017-05-16 12:00:04    {Cat1}
Name: label, dtype: object

print(df_A)

             timestamp values   label
0  2017-05-16 12:00:02      x  {Cat1}
1  2017-05-16 12:00:04      x  {Cat1}
2  2017-08-12 22:01:06      Y     NaN
```